# Using a Loop to make a Spatial Join between shapefile and data frames

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

I have a polygon shape file and a series of data frames. **What I want to do** is to create a loop that will make a 'Spatial Join' between the shape file and all those data frames, but I keep getting an error. Any ideas on this?

Here is the code of my loop

```
datasets <- c("df1","df2","df3")

for (i in datasets){
     gridpolygon <- sp::merge(gridpolygon, i, by = "id", sort = FALSE) #Spatial Join
     }

> Error in table(y[, by.y]) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Here is a reproducible example in three steps.

(1) Create a regular gridded polygon from a random polygon

```
# Load libraries
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(dismo)
library(data.table)

### create a regular gridded polygon from a random polygon 

# create polygon Random Polygon
    set.seed(1)
    dat <- matrix(stats::rnorm(2000), ncol = 2)
    ch <- chull(dat)
    coords <- dat[c(ch, ch[1]), ]  # closed polygon
    sp_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(coords)), ID=1)))
    plot(sp_poly)

# create a regular gridded polygon
    # Create an empty raster
    grid <- raster(extent(sp_poly))

    # Choose its resolution.
    res(grid) <- 1 

    # coordinate reference system 
    proj4string(grid)<-CRS("++proj=utm +zone=48") # set it to UTM

    # Transform this raster into a polygon
    gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(grid)

    # Create and ID variable of Grid Cells 
    gridpolygon@data$id = rownames(gridpolygon@data)    
    plot(gridpolygon)
```

(2) Create data frames

```
  df1 <- data.table(id=seq(1:5), x=c(11:15))
  df2 <- data.table(id=seq(1:5), y=c(21:25))
  df3 <- data.table(id=seq(1:5), z=c(31:35))
```

(3) Try the loop

```
datasets <- c("df1","df2","df3")

for (i in datasets){
     gridpolygon <- sp::merge(gridpolygon, i, by = "id", sort = FALSE) #Spatial Join
     }

> Error in table(y[, by.y]) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I get the correct result if I make the spatial joins one by one but this would not solve my problem since I have too many data sets

```
# Spatial join, one by one
  gridpolygon <- sp::merge(gridpolygon, df1, by = "id", sort = FALSE) 
  gridpolygon <- sp::merge(gridpolygon, df2, by = "id", sort = FALSE) 
  gridpolygon <- sp::merge(gridpolygon, df3, by = "id", sort = FALSE)
```

Comment: try `get(i)` instead of `i` in your loop, this will get the dataframe while `i` is just the characters "df1"

Comment: Thank you @NicE ! It was really such a simple mistake ! thank you, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution proposed by @NicE in the comments. It's simply a matter of using `get(i)` instead of `i` inside the loop.

```
  for (i in datasets){
    gridpolygon <- sp::merge(gridpolygon, get(i), by = "id", sort = FALSE)
  }
```